# How to import raven db with versioning bundle

Tags: ravendb

I have a database with versioning bundle turned on. I make an export and then try to import the exported dump to newly created db. I get the exception "Modifying a historical revisionis not allowed". I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/5mp151HCiL8) question and answer from Ayende, that its by design. But how do I import data to an empty database if the versioning bundle was turned on and there are revisions in it?

For now I did the following thing: I make a new database without a versioning bundle, but with replication bundle in it. Import to that db(and it works), but I have a lot of duplicates if I perform search.

After that I create another new database, with replication and versioning bundle turned on. And I replicate from the db with duplicates this db. And it works, but it seems its a lot of things todo.

Am I doing the right thing? Is there an easier way to get your data from the dump?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue. The ONLY way I could get the import to work was to do the following:

1. Create DB with Versioning enabled (*They recommend that DBs be created with any bundles that may be used*).
2. Disable the versioning bundle. I've done this by editing the database settings and removing the bundle from the "Raven/ActiveBundles" setting.
3. Import your database.
4. Enable the versioning bundle. Just add the "Versioning" bundle back to the "Raven/ActiveBundles" setting.

If anyone has a better idea, I'd love to hear it. :)

Comment: I am having the same issue with V3 and there's nowhere where I can find the answer. So I give a +1 on this answer

Comment: Here's the thread with the same answer you have from Oren Eini https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/GMI4X0wV4qQ

Answer (score 0):

The new version of RavenDb 3.0 give the permission to import with the Bundle already activated. So all the trick of disabling and enabling is not of any use anymore. But you might have new issues like Index not in synch with your revision or having the "versioning" not displayed in the Settings=>Versioning window.

To fix your versioning if they don't show in the versioning window but that they are visible in the System Documents, you need to add the Id individually or run some kind of code.

**Option parameter for import since RavenDb 3.0.3745**:
--disable-versioning-during-import

**Fix of Versioning not containing an Id :**

```
        private void UpdateVersioning(string destinationRavenDbServer, string databaseName)
    {
        using (var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = destinationRavenDbServer, DefaultDatabase = databaseName })
        {
            documentStore.Initialize();
            using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                var versioningInfoList = session.Advanced.LoadStartingWith<RavenJObject>("Raven/Versioning/", pageSize: 1024 );

                foreach (var versioningInfo in versioningInfoList)
                {
                    if (!versioningInfo.ContainsKey("Id"))
                    {
                        var fullInternalId = session.Advanced.GetDocumentId(versioningInfo);
                        var idSplitted = fullInternalId.Split('/');
                        var newId = idSplitted[idSplitted.Length - 1];
                        versioningInfo.Add("Id", newId);
                    }
                }

                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Fix for re-indexing all the database**:

```
        private void ResetAllIndexes(string destinationRavenDbServer, string databaseName)
    {
        using (var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = destinationRavenDbServer, DefaultDatabase = databaseName })
        {
            documentStore.Initialize();
            var indexes = documentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetIndexNames(0, 1024); // Update the 1024 first index, but you get the idea

            foreach (var indexName in indexes)
            {
                documentStore.DatabaseCommands.ResetIndex(indexName);
            }
        } 
    }
```